# Exporting JAR file from Eclipse doesn't include folders/files outside src

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to export a jar file using eclipse but it doesn't include any folder or file outside the src. I have an images folder and 2 csv files that I need to be in the jar file so the images can be displayed and for the csv files to be loaded. When I run in eclipse the images are displayed and the csv files are loaded but when I export as jar file they don't.

```
background.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images\\marvel_800_500.png"));
```

This is how I'm setting the images

```
public static void loadAbilities(String filePath)
```

.

```
loadAbilities("Abilities.csv");
```

How can I include the folder/files in the jar file or load them in any way?

[Java Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKtVT.png)

Comment: You just need to put your resources [in the right place for Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: @g00se It worked for the images but not for the csv file. When I run in Eclipse the images and the csv file work but when I import as jar the csv file doesnt work. "Invalid file path"

This works for the images.
`background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/marvel_800_500.png")));`

This works in eclipse but not in jar

`public static void loadAbilities(String filePath) throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));`

`loadAbilities((getClass().getResource("/resources/Abilities.csv")).getPath());`

Comment: Sorry. Try this `try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/foo.csv")))) {
            // Code here
        }
`

Comment: Will add as answer if you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/foo.csv")))) {
    // Code here
}
```

Is the correct way to read a resource with a `BufferedReader`